# Table Background-Color Transparency doesn't work on ipad or safari

Tags: html, ipad, safari, html-table, transparency

I have read in many places that this was an issue with Safari. Basically, the problem is, I want my table to be completely transparent except for the writing. I have been playing around with the idea of somehow setting opacity on the background only. I'm not sure where to start though as I am still learning HTML and CSS.

How can I make the table blend in completely with everything else? Is this possible yet?

Comment: if you don't set any background-color for your table it should be transparent anyway - [this shows as red in safari for me](http://jsfiddle.net/RMyKH/)

Comment: no it goes white but the background for the website is grey. Your example is colouring the body red not the table

Comment: Could you change the example to the code as you have it so I can see what your actual problem is as you haven't described it very well